# Handle multiple users in Node js Express application

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to NodeJs, and as a practice I am trying to build a blogging API using node and express. I am looking for a way to implement the following tasks :

- Any user should be able to look at other user's profile, but not edit it.
- Any user should be able to view any blog but edit only their own blogs

The way I was thinking of doing this is :

- When a user logs in, store the user's id in a cookie (either a JWT token or something else), and whenever a profile / blog is to be displayed, check if the author of the blog / profile has the same Id as the one stored in cookie, if it is then allow the option to edit, else don't.

Would like to know if this is correct way to do it, also are there any better ways to achieve this ?

Comment: I would suggest if you can go through few articles, like this https://vegibit.com/node-js-blog-tutorial/
and try to figure out, because there are lots of resources available for this

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use an authentication middleware:

This blog post briefed it: https://medium.com/quick-code/handling-authentication-and-authorization-with-node-7f9548fedde8

The explanation of the concept is that you do not need to add the auth middleware to the user's profile GET endpoint (i.e the endpoints that gets user profile).

To edit a blog you need to do some checks if the id of the one who created the blog post matches.

I have a project you can check: https://github.com/razaqfatiu/Teamwork/blob/develop/api/controllers/article.js

The editArticle function on line 41 should be of help